# OVR Lip Sync in Unity WebGL project

Tags: unity, webgl, unity-webgl, browser, avatar

I am using the Oculus VR (OVR) Lip Sync Plugin for an avatar in a Unity project which I want to deploy to a browser using WebGL.

The issue is that WebGL doesn't support Unity's `Microphone` API. I know that some aspects of OVR Lip Sync use `Microphone` for real-time Lip Sync of voice through a mic, but I just need it to generate Lip Sync from prerecorded audio files. This doesn't actually need a microphone but it seems to want to use the `Microphone` API.

I tried commenting out the *OVRLipSyncMicInput.cs* class where it invokes the `Microphone` API. The project works fine with lip sync in the Unity editor. The WebGL project builds and runs but the lip sync is not working.

The actual error I get when trying to build the project before commenting out the *OVRLipSyncMicInput.cs* class is:
*Assets\Oculus\LipSync\Scripts\OVRLipSyncMicInput.cs: error CS0103: The name 'Microphone' does not exist in the current context*

Does anyone know if it is possible to get the OVR Lip Sync plugin to work with WebGL or if there is another way to deploy a Unity project to a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't a way to get the Oculus VR Lip Sync plugin to work in a WebGL Unity project, and there isn't another way to deploy a Unity project to a browser without WebGL, so the only solution is to find another Lip Sync plugin that works in WebGL such as [AmplitudeSALSA](https://crazyminnowstudio.com/posts/salsa-lipsync-in-webgl-with-amplitude/).

Comment: I can confirm that I purchased AmplitudeSALSA and got lip sync working in WebGL using it.

Answer (score -1):

A coworker was able to get that working using using Microphone Pro and some custom code.

Comment: This answer would be more useful to future readers if it included guidance about how to write this "custom code", so they can implement the solution you describe.